# Jenkins Blue Ocean set default language?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-blueocean

After install blue ocean , the default language is depend on browser language setting.

How can i set the default language to en_us ?

I find a way that work on Jenkins classic mode with plugin [Locale Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Locale+Plugin),but not work on blue ocean.

second way is set url with paramter like: https://ci.jenkins-ci.org/blue/pipelines/?language=en , but it's not my best soulction.